# JBOSS database failover - What happens when secondary database fails?

Tags: database, jboss, failover

I am using jboss-4.0.5.GA. I have a primary and secondary database configured in the -*ds.xml. When the primary fails the secondary takes over. What happens in our case is the secondary also fails and I would like to connect to the primary database now? But what I see is if the secondary fails it is not trying to connect to priamary.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Tried this and it worked. To connect back to to the primary again we would need to configure the URL as below.

Primary|Secondary|Primary